# Python correctly finding and reading windows application event logs

Tags: python, windows, bash, events

so my ultimate goal is to use python to read a specific application's windows event log when triggered by a file update.

Here is my problem, python I believe does not have access to the event logs stored in C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs. Whenever I try to read the files I get the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I tried every form of escaping, string split/join and using quotes on the file path and I always get the same error. I even cheaply used the os.system('dir "C:\Windows\System32..."') command in the python command prompt to list directories higher in the path for the log to verify access and I receive similar errors up to the C:\Windows\System32 directory, that one will list just fine.

Example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs - File not found
C:\Windows\System32\winevt - File not found
C:\Windows\System32 - Lists files
```

I know these directories exist. So from here I figured I could use a bash script to copy the event log into a temp folder for python to read. I wrote a real simple bash script containing:

```
xcopy /Y "C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\XXXXXXX" c:\Temp
```

(XXXXXXX) being the name of the log I want to copy for the python script.

The bash script runs fine on its own but when called by my python script it fails, refuses to copy the file because it can't find it. I have even tried using py2exe to create an exe to then run in administrator mode. This failed too. With similar errors of the file not found. I'm not sure I understand the permissions python uses to call the script and why the bash script cannot copy the file even when it can do it in a normal command prompt.

Any suggestions or flaws you can point out in my logic would be great. I am very stuck.

Comment: Please, consider revising your question in a sense that clearly points out, what is your actual problem and what is the desired outcome. Right now, you only provide verbal descriptions of stuff you have tried. If you provided actual code and actual error messages it would greatly help answering the problem.

Comment: I tried running `os.listdir("c:\windows\system32\winevt\logs")` and `open("c:\windows\system32\winevt\logs\system.evtx")` and they worked fine. I'm thinking there's something wrong with your install or permissions.

Comment: @Salax I tried the same commands you posted on a virtual machine and it works! Strange that my one install is acting up. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, hopefully you get yours figured out.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a 32bits python on a 64bit install of windows.

> In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64

You can use os.listdir("c:\windows\sysnative\winevt\logs") as a workaround to read from the real system32 dir from a 32bit python interpretter runing on a 64bit windows...

Sources:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942589